# Extending DataForm Web part Not showing Node Value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dataformwebpart

I'm trying to create a custom web part by inheriting the dataformwebpart. the problem i'm facing is that in xsl i'm not able to display value of xml nodes although i'm getting the names of nodes.

below is my sample code, xsl, xml

```
 public override void DataBind()
    {

      XmlDocument doc = GetFeedsXML(); 
      XmlDataSource source = new XmlDataSource();
      source.ID = "wallXML";
      source.Data = doc.InnerXml;
      this.DataSource = source;
      base.Xsl = this.Xsl;
      base.DataBind();

    }
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" version="1.0"

exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt"

xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"

xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
<xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">

<div>

<table>

<xsl:for-each select="/root/data/*">
        <tr><td>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
abcd
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</td></tr>
        </xsl:for-each>


</table>
</div>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xml

```
<root>
 <data>
  <id>166358820071963_158352987564493</id>
  <from>
   <name>Sharepointworld By Ashutosh</name>
   <category>Personal blog</category>
   <id>166358820071963</id>
  </from>
  <message>http://www.sharepointworld.in/2011/06/filestream-with-sharepoint-2010.html</message>
  <picture>http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDBGCIsqUOyGsf0&amp;w=90&amp;h=90&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharepoint.microsoft.com%2Fblog%2FPublishingImages%2FBlog+images_Filestream%2Fblog_filestream_3.PNG</picture>
  <link>http://www.sharepointworld.in/2011/06/filestream-with-sharepoint-2010.html</link>
  <name>SharePoint World By Ashutosh: FILESTREAM with SharePoint 2010</name>
  <caption>www.sharepointworld.in</caption>
  <description>Ashutosh blog for sharepoint world</description>
  <icon>http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif</icon>
  <actions>
   <name>Comment</name>
   <link>http://www.facebook.com/166358820071963/posts/158352987564493</link>
  </actions>
  <actions>
   <name>Like</name>
   <link>http://www.facebook.com/166358820071963/posts/158352987564493</link>
  </actions>
  <privacy>
   <description>Everyone</description>
   <value>EVERYONE</value>
  </privacy>
  <type>link</type>
  <created_time>2011-06-01T08:03:00+0000</created_time>
  <updated_time>2011-06-01T08:03:00+0000</updated_time>
 </data>
</root>
```

kindly suggest where i'm going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for the same i had to override one more method

```
protected override XPathNavigator GetXPathNavigator(string viewPath)

        {

            return doc.CreateNavigator();

        }
```